# Overloading Ostream operator

Tags: c++, overloading, this, operator-keyword

I found that when i create ostream operator within a class or a struct
it only accepts one parameter as the second is This pointer
so i tried to do it this way and it is not working though

P.S I know that i should create it outside the class or the struct as a free function But I am trying to understand why ?

```
struct Vector2 
{
    float x,y ; 
    Vector2(float ax , float ay )
    {
        x = ax ; 
        y = ay ; 
    }
    std:: ostream&  operator<< (std::ostream&  stream )
    { 
        return stream <<this->x<< " , "<< this->y ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Member functions are called with `ObjOfVector2 << cout;`, the argument before the operator must be the object of your class. You want `cout << ObjOfVector2;`, that can only be done with the free function or C++20, if I remember correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `<<` is overloaded, `a << b` means either

```
operator<<(a,b)
```

if the overload is a free function, or

```
a.operator<<(b)
```

if it is a member.

That is, for an operator defined as a member, the left-hand argument is `*this`, and you need to write

```
Vector2 v;
v << std::cout;
```

wihch is equivalent to

```
Vector2 v;
v.operator<<(std::cout);
```